# How create a function that finds a value contained in another excel file with two conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I briefly comment on my problem to solve, what I want is to create a function that gives you two conditions and I find a value but in another excel file (Workbook) that meets these 2 conditions.

In an Origen.xlsx file where the data I want to obtain, there are 3 columns [Fecha, Data1 and Data2]:

[Origen.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5Jcn.png)

It is a Destino.xlsm file where I put two conditions [Fecha and Data1] and below the result cell I want to use the function to create that finds from the Data2 column of the source.xlsx file the value that meets the two conditions:

[Destino.xlsm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVX97.png)

Here I send you an idea of ​​what I have of code, I get the data but only if it meets a condition and I can not put it as a function for which the cells are fixed.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B97Pc.png)

```
Sub Macro()
    With Sheets("Hoja1")
        With .Range("C2")
            .Formula = "=IFERROR(vlookup(A2,'C:\Users\fcaballero\Desktop\Nueva carpeta\[Origen.xlsx]Hoja1'!$A$2:$C$10,3,FALSE),""No"")"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I would greatly appreciate your support, greetings in advance.
I attached the files in a zip.
http://excelgali.mejorforo.net/download.forum?id=621

Comment: Hello Nelo - Please edit your post with the code from the picture you provided.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a **[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have **[tried so far](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding **[how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**, and take the **[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)**

Comment: Add a helper column on your Origen workbook. Add it in the first column of your table and have it be =Fecha&Data1 to concatenate those. Then, in Destino do a Vlookup `=VLookUp(A1&B1,{sourceData},4,False)`. No VBA needed.

Comment: Thanks, now what I would like to do is in the vba vary A1 & B1 with a for (A1 & B1, A2 & B2, A2 & B2, ...),

`Sub Macro()
With Sheets("Hoja1")
For i = 1 To 3
a = i + 1
With .Range("C" & a)
n = "A" & a & "&B" & a
.Formula = "=IFERROR(vlookup(n,'C:\Users\fcaballero\Desktop\Nueva carpeta\[Origen.xlsx]Hoja1'!$A$2:$D$10,4,FALSE),""No"")"
.Value = .Value
End With
Next
End With
End Sub`

Comment: Why do you need VBA?  isn't this what you want? [How to create a unique distinct list where other columns meet two criteria](https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/06/27/how-to-create-a-unique-distinct-list-where-other-columns-meet-two-criteria/)

Comment: I may be wrong but a UDF that grabs a value from another workbook will be fine when the other workbook is available but when it is not, and the function recalculates e.g. on workbook open/refresh, you may be left with an error message.  Better to use non vba or a procedure.

Comment: Thanks to all, I could solve it

Comment: Thanks to Fernando J. Rivera who gave me the basic idea, what he did not want is to edit the origen file

Comment: Profex the code that you teach to me seems very useful when you do not have knowledge if there are repeated data and this generates me the list with the given conditions. But in my case it is to find a single data with the given conditions even if they are repeated since it emphasizes that something is wrong with the Origen file.

Comment: QHarr, What I do not want is that you have to open the origen file. thankyou